# IConversionManager not found in documents4j while converting docx to pdf (have all the binaries)

Tags: documents4j

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com/documents4j/conversion/IConversionManager at 
com.test.resume.Documents4jPOC.main(Documents4jPOC.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.documents4j.conversion.IConversionManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:428)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:417)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:416)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:494)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:427)
```

[image: Dependencies snapshot]

I'm getting the above exception when trying to convert docx to pdf using documents4j. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the API package which contains this class. Ideally, use Maven or another tool for managing your dependencies what avoids such errors.

Comment: Rafael Winterhalter thanks for the reply. I resolved the issue by figuring out the API package. Will documents4j work on unix machine or is the solution only for Windows machine ?

Comment: There is a server and client api but it requires windows to run word.

Comment: Just want to be clear on my understand. Documents4j has a server and client api which can run on linux/unix machines, but the msoffice used by documents4j needs to installed/run on a windows machine only. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: You can run a documents4j server on a windows machine and unse the remoteconverter that implements the iconverter interface to drive the conversion from a linux machine.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael Winterhalter